# Includes and classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, compiler-construction, include, forward-declaration

Well, i have the following problem.. I have main.cpp

```
#include "serverClass.h"
...
```

and then in serverClass.h,

```
#ifndef SERVERCLASS_H_
#define SERVERCLASS_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "clientThread.h"
....
```

and in clientThread,

```
class ClientThread {
private:
serverClass* server;
....
```

But when it tries to compile ClientThread, it says serverClass isn't a type, because it wasn't compiled yet. I can't avoid including clientThread.h in serverClass. Is there anyway to tell the compiler that there is a type called serverClass that wasn't compiled yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to forward delcare `serverClass`:

```
class serverClass;

class ClientThread {
private:
serverClass* server;
....
```

Answer (score 2):

In clientThread.h, before `ClientThread` class definition, you can  [*forward-declare*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20forward-declaration) the `ServerClass` class:

```
// Forward declaration
class ServerClass;

class ClientThread {
private:
ServerClass* server;
 ....
```